# Custom dynamic widgets with FlutterFlow

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow, custom-widgets, custom-code

I'm seeking guidance on creating dynamic widgets in FlutterFlow.

I currently have a list of employee names stored in Firestore and want to design a page that displays all the names alongside textboxes. I aim to create a daily scoring system where I can input scores for each name.

Should there be one record for a specific day (with all the name x scores) or a unique record for each date x name x score combination? What way of storing data is a better way for flutterflow and performance?

And what is the right way of dynamically creating a list of widgets connected to Firestore records in Flutterflow? Thank you very much.